# Shifting a 1 bit into high and 0 bit into low in arithmetic compression

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

I'm trying to write my own arithmetic compressor. I'm cheating a little bit by referencing the implementation I found in https://marknelson.us/posts/2014/10/19/data-compression-with-arithmetic-coding.html
. Specifically, this part:

(Note that this code is incomplete and the author later updates this code to be complete, but for the purpose of my question, this part will suffice.)

```
  unsigned int high = 0xFFFFFFFFU;
  unsigned int low = 0;
  char c;
  while ( input >> c ) {
    int range = high - low + 1;
    prob p = model.getProbability(c);
    high = low + (range * p.upper)/p.denominator;
    low = low + (range * p.lower)/p.denominator;
    for ( ; ; ) {
      if ( high < 0x80000000U )
        output_bit( 0 );
      else if ( low >= 0x80000000U )
        output_bit( 1 );
      else
        break;
      low <<= 1;
      high << = 1;
      high |= 1;
    }
  }
```

Below this code, the author has the following description:

> We shift in a 1 into the least significant bit of high, and a 0 into the least significant of low. Thus, we keep working on 32 bits of precision by expelling the bits that no longer contribute anything to the precision of our calculations. In this particular implementation, we just keep 32 bits in working registers, with some additional number already sent to the output, and some other number pending for input.

I have several questions about this. First, I don't quite understand why we shift a `1` as opposed to a `0` into `high`. Is it because we want to maximize the value of `high`? Second, the author seems to claim that `0` was shifted into the least significant bit of `low`, but I don't see where this is done explicitly and if it's not explicitly done, I don't see how the above algorithm guarantees that the least significant bit of `low` is 0?

Comment: `low <<= 1;` shifts low to left, basically adding 0 on the right, ie `0 was shifted into the least significant bit of low`

Comment: @IłyaBursov Ahh I mixed up left and right shift operators. I was thinking they were halving `high` and `low` with the `<<=`, but they're actually doubling it. It seems I do not actually understand this algorithm

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is to maximize the distance between `low` and `high`.
2. `<<= 1` always shifts a zero into the low bit.

Comment: when you do `low <<= 1;` i understand that this gets rid of the most significant bit, but I don't understand why we do this as opposed to, say, setting the most significant to 0? it seems if we set it to 0, this will make `high - low` larger than doing `low <<= 1`?

Comment: `low` and `high` must always be shifted by the _same_ number of bits, in order to keep the portions of the fractions they represent lined up.